# strange laravel query builder behaviour with dashes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This:

```
$stockCodes = \DB::connection('sage_accounts')
->table('sales_order_items')
->select('stock_code')
->from('sales_order_items')
->orderBy('stock_code')
->distinct()->get();
```

returns any stock code with an RDxxx-xx-H7-xx stock code format, but that's the incorrect format. The correct format is RDxxx-Hx-xx-xx. That query doesn’t return stock codes in that format. Take, for example sales order line item 11649, which has stock code RD0448-H7-09-28.  It is not returned with the rest of the stock codes, and this:

```
$stockCodes = \DB::connection('sage_accounts')
->table('sales_order_items')
->select('stock_code')
->from('sales_order_items')
->where('id', 11649)
->orderBy('stock_code')
->distinct()->get();
```

Returns an empty data set.  While this:

```
select distinct `stock_code` from `sales_order_items` 
where `id` = 11649 order by `stock_code` asc
```

returns the correct data

Why will query builder not return items where the stock code is in format RDBxxxx-Hxx ?

Comment: I think you may use it without `->from('sales_order_items')`

Comment: You are quite right, but that still doesn't get me my data

Comment: What gives you this: `$stockCodes = \DB::connection('sage_accounts')->table('sales_order_items')->select('stock_code')->where('id', 11649)->first()`?

Comment: It gets me "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stock_code‌​' in 'field list'"

Field is there, table is there.  Error message gives the sql as:
at PDO->prepare('select `stock_code‌​` from `sales_order_items` where `id` = ? limit 1')

that should work.  I have to go to a meeting, thank you for your help so far, I'll be back later.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try this,</strike>

```
$stockCodes = \DB::connection('sage_accounts')
->table('sales_order_items')
->select('stock_code')
->from('sales_order_items')
->orderBy('stock_code', 'asc')
->distinct()
->get();
```

---

> **Update**

You can try executing **raw sql** on your connection like this:

```
$stockCodes = \DB::connection('sage_accounts')
->select('select distinct stock_code from sales_order_items where id = :id order by stock_code asc', ['id' => 11649]);
```

Without running a trial and error, it is difficult to figure out where exactly the query execution is going wrong.

> *[Listening for query events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#listening-for-query-events)* could point us towards an explanation. Use the `dd` function in your **`AppServiceProvider`'s `boot`** method, to view and **debug** the sql queries that get executed when you run the select statement -

```
public function boot()
{
    DB::listen(function ($query) {
        dd($query);
    });
}
```

If the problem still persists, do upload some screenshots of your table in concern.

Comment: no that made no difference.  RD0448-02-H7-27 is returned, RD0448-H7-02-27 isn't.

Comment: @gedq try the updated answer and share the results please.

Comment: "select distinct stock_code from sales_order_items order by stock_code asc" That's the sql.

Answer (score 1):

u may use this one DB::select('your_query');

```
DB::select('select distinct stock_code from sales_order_items 
where id = 11649 order by stock_code asc');
```

Comment: result says [] It didn't return the record  This is puzzling the heck out of me.

Comment: gedq  srry for late reply?? I was out of internet.is your problem solved??

Comment: Indirectly yes; it looks like sysadmin has been playing with a new cache configuration.  If I flush all caches beforehand the problem disappears.  Not a long term solution but at least I know where the problem is now.